# Command Button Action Not getting called

Tags: controller

.common
        {
        display:none;
        }
        .test
        {
        border-style: none;
        }

table.list {
    border-width: 0 !important;
}

tr.dataRow td {
    border-bottom-width: 0 !important;
}

```
             <apex:selectList value="{!selectedVal}" size="1">
             <apex:selectOptions value="{!Indication}"></apex:selectOptions>
             <apex:actionSupport action="{!displayBrandData}" event="onchange"></apex:actionSupport>
              </apex:selectList>
              <!--Not Needed Custom Label Part-->
               <apex:outputText value="Q1:{!$Label.RSA_Q1}" escape="false" rendered="{!selectedVal=='RSA'}"></apex:outputText>
               <apex:outputText value="Q1:{!$Label.PSO}" escape="false" rendered="{!selectedVal=='PCO'}"></apex:outputText>
                 <apex:pageblockTable value="{!squestions}" var="p" id="theaddrs"  headerclass="common" border="0" >

                   <apex:column >
                   <b><apex:outputText value="{!p.Labels__c}" rendered="{!p.IsLabelRequired__c}"/></b>
                   </apex:column>

                   <apex:column value="{!p.QuestionText1__c}"/>


                   </apex:pageblockTable> 

                      <apex:pageblockTable value="{!sanswers}" var="p"  headerclass="common" styleclass="test">
                   <apex:column rendered="{!p.chkboxAnswer__c}">
                   <apex:selectList value="{!selectedVal1}" size="1">
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!RSAAnswers}"></apex:selectOptions>
                 </apex:selectList>

                  <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!selectedVal1}">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!RSAAnswersCheckBox}" />
                    </apex:selectCheckboxes>

                   </apex:column>

                   </apex:pageblockTable> 

        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

In the above code I am trying to fetch the selectedVal1 which is the dropdown/checkbox selected value in the server side controller but the strange thing I noticed is that the command button action "savesurvey" itself is not getting called.I checked the debug logs as well but didn't find the function getting called at all.

Could you please let me know where the problem is?

Comment: I don't see any command button or "savesurvey" present in the given code.

Comment: It is there....May be for some reason it is not showing.This is the code for command button which is being used    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!saveSurvey}" value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>